# multiple tables with the same TD width

Tags: html, css, html-table

To format these  2 tables I have a css sheet. The top table is a filter/sort selection. The second is a scrollable data table.

```css
     div#scrollTableContainer {
     width: auto;
     margin: 20px; /* just for presentation purposes */
     border: 1px solid black;
     }

    #tHeadContainer {
        background: #CC3600;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #tBodyContainer {
        height: 750px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
        td:first-child {
        min-width: 5%; /* EDIT */
        max-width: 5%;
        border-left:0;
    }

    td:first-child + td {
        min-width: 4%; 
        max-width: 4%;
    }

    td:first-child + td + td {
        min-width: 4%; 
        max-width: 4%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="scrollTableContainer">
    <div id="tHeadContainer">
    <table border="1" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
    <th bgcolor="<%=bgc0%>">USED</th>
    <th bgcolor="<%=bgc0%>">STATUS</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>                     
          
    <div id="tBodyContainer">   
    <table border="1" align="center" id="tBody" class="TableData">
    <td> stuff </td>
    <td> More stuff </td>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Neither of the 2 tables are aligning column wise so that the Title/Header columns do not match the tables columns below. It also shows almost the same in chrome/IE, but firefox is a complete shamble.

Im at a loss to get this right guys, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have an inline width of 100% set on the top table and not the bottom table. That will be why they are out of alignment. Also inline width is now deprecated, you're better using `style="width:100%"` for a more portable and canonical solution.

Comment: And also there is a scrollbar on the bottom container and not the top, that will also affect alignment.

Comment: I added an extra row to cover that extra real estate in the scroll bar. Good catch  :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#scrollTableContainer {
  width: auto;
  margin: 20px;
  /* just for presentation purposes */
}

#tHeadContainer {
  background: #CC3600;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tBodyContainer {
  height: 750px;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
  min-width: 15%;
  max-width: 15%;
  width: 15%;
}

td:first-child+td {
  min-width: 4%;
  max-width: 4%;
}

td:first-child+td+td {
  min-width: 4%;
  max-width: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollTableContainer">
  <div id="tHeadContainer">
    <table border="1" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="<%=bgc0%>">USED</th>
        <th bgcolor="<%=bgc0%>">STATUS</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tBodyContainer">
    <table border="1" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <td> stuff </td>
      <td> More stuff </td>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to align the columns of both table vertically right?
If that is so, I have a solution for you 
I have changed your css and u missed tr in second table.

https://jsfiddle.net/9ccwkoav/

```
div#scrollTableContainer {
 width: auto;
 margin: 20px; /* just for presentation purposes */
 border: 1px solid black;
 }

#tHeadContainer {
    background: #CC3600;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#tHeadContainer th{
 width:50%; 
}
#tBodyContainer {
    height: 750px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
 .TableData{
   width:100%;
 }
 .TableData td{
 width:50%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Notice that there will be a little margin because of the scroll bar of the second table, but you can easily change it by adding a tab in the first array with the width of the scrollbar. Hope it will help

```css
#scrollTableContainer {
 width : 96%;
 margin : auto;
 border : 1px solid #ccc;
}

#tHeadContainer {
 background-color : green;
 width : 100%;
}

#tBodyContainer {
 width : 100%;
 height : 750px;
 overflow-y : scroll;
}

#tHeadContainer table, #tBodyContainer table {
 border-collapse : collapse;
 width : 100%;
}

td, th {
 border : 1px solid black;
}

tr {
 width : 100%;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
 min-width : 15%;
 max-width : 15%;
 width : 15%; /* Tweak this value to change the first column width */
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollTableContainer">

 <div id="tHeadContainer">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>USED</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
 <div id="tBodyContainer">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Some other stuff</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
</div>
```